# Select all Users, order them by their comments count

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In a Rails application I want to fetch all users, ordered by their count of comments, to get the top-ten commenters. How do I do that, specifically?

In my model, User and Comment are in a HABTM relationship to each other.

Right now I have:

```
  all_users = User.all :joins => :comments
  all_users.sort_by do |user| 
    user.comments.count
  end
```

I'm still stuck with the fact that this delivers multiple entries for one user, as one user might have more than one comment. And I still have to get the first ten users only.

**What would be a more efficient way to do this**, e.g. in the query itself?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can always do

```
User.all(:joins => :comments, :group => 'users.id', :order => 'count(*)')
```

if it does not hit your db performance

Answer (score 3):

If you had your `belongs_to :user` in the Comment model configured like this:

```
belongs_to :user, :counter_cache => true
```

And then you had a `comments_count` integer field defaulting to 0 in your `users` table, then you would be able to order by that rather than having to do a join.

Comment: Thank you, Ryan. In my particular set-up, a `User` and `Comment` are in a HABTM relationship to each other, so what would I do then?